Exclude Projects post type from wordpress search
I would like to remove our projects from the search bar results in WordPress. I have come across the following snippet to do so, however, this method is by listing all the post IDs. Is there a way to exclude all /projects/ at once?
function ss_search_filter( $query ) {
    if ( !$query->is_admin && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 1, 2, 3 ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ss_search_filter' );


This question is similar to: stop wordpress search showing a custom post type. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you. Are projects considered post types ?

I see, projects are not a post type, so I would need to create a custom post type to exclude. Is that about right?

What are your projects then? Why do you have a /projects/ slug? Are they just pages with a parent page of projects? No you do not have to create a custom post type, we just need to know how they are setup.

Apparently, Divi (We are using Divi) comes with a default custom post type called  "Projects."
I have added "Projects" to the exclusion but search results still display projects.

This is using the snippet provided at, stop wordpress search showing a custom post type.
PS when I searched "exclude projects from wp search bar results" that page did not appear. Thanks again!

Specifically,
// can exclude multiple post types, for ex. array('staticcontent', 'cpt2', 'cpt3')
$post_types_to_exclude = array('projects');

Since this is Divi, the Project post type is custom. You should be able to use the following filter. Note, there were some errors in the initial function specifically is_search() and is_admin() are $query Object methods, so you should use the () to denote. Also, the $query needs to be returned - or it won't work as expected.
function ss_search_filter( $query ) {
    // If the query is_admin() bail
    if ( $query->is_admin() ) :
        return $query;
    endif;
    
    // If the query is_search and is_main_query
    if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // set the post type to only post types you want returned.
        $query->set( 'post_type', ['page', 'post' ] );
    }
    
    // Return the query.
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ss_search_filter' );


Absolutely amazing. Thank you, disinfor! I could also apply products and it works. Have a great day and all the best!
